# Print series of number every 50

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, recursion, functional-programming

I need to paginate through an API and I am creating the URLs.

The URL looks like this: 
`/search/officers?q=XXXXX&items_per_page=50&start_index={}`

The maximum items per page allowed in the returned JSON is 50, and based on the number of pages I need to change the `start_index={}` string.

I calculated the number of pagination i need to execute by dividing the number of total results by the maximum items per page.

```
pages = 355 
count_by_n = 50

for i in range(pages+1):
    if i is 0:
        print("start_index={}".format(i))
    else:
        global count_by_n 
        count_by_n += 50
        print(str("start_index={}".format(str(count_by_n + 1))))`
```

which produces:

```
start_index=0
start_index=101
start_index=151
start_index=201
start_index=251
start_index=301
start_index=351
start_index=401

<>:7: SyntaxWarning: name 'count_by_n' is assigned to before global declaration
```

Technically it is the result i want but I was wondering if there was a way to get around that message and maybe solve this with recursion.

Comment: Why do you start with `start_index=0`? Furthermore `51` is missing.

Comment: Cuz the first page is from 0 to 50, the second page from 51 to 100. Yes, I figured after posting, editing now.

Comment: but that does not make much sense, either the first page is from 1 to 50 (and the second from 51 to 100), or the first page is from 0 to 49, and the second from 50 to 99. Otherwise the two pages have a different number of elements. It is also not in "harmony" with the later requests you do, since then you fetch from `101` to `151` which thus makes a hop of 50, not of 51.

Comment: You're right it's from 1 to 50 - 51 to 100 etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the `start` (inclusive), `stop` (exclusive) and `step` in a range, so you can write this as:

```
pages = 123
count_by_n = 50

for i in range(1, 50*pages + 1, 50):
    print('start_index={}'.format(i))
```

This then yields:

```
>>> pages = 355
>>> for i in range(1, 50*pages + 1, 50):
...     print('start_index={}'.format(i))
... 
start_index=1
start_index=51
start_index=101
start_index=151
start_index=201
start_index=251
start_index=301
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already calculated your pagination, IMHO the easiest solution would be to simply iterate over that range and print `50*i + 1`:

```
pages = 355
for i in range(pages):
    print(f'start_index={50*i+1}')

# start_index=1
# start_index=51                                              
# start_index=101              
# ... 
# start_index=17601
# start_index=17651                                         
# start_index=17701
```

---

And if you do *not* want to calculate the number of pages beforehand, because you want to do that loop based on the number of urls `n`, I'd recommend to do

```
n = 17710
for i in range(0, n, 50):
    print(f'start_index={i+1}')
```

for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 1):

The `SyntaxWarning` occurs because `global count_by_n` is being evaluated multiple times in the for loop and, more importantly, after a value has already been assigned to the variable. In order to get rid of the warning you should use the `global` keyword only once per variable (and thus outside the for loop) and **before assigning a value**, like so:

```
pages = 123
global count_by_n
count_by_n = 50

for i in range(pages+1):
    if i is 0:
        print("start_index={}".format(i))
    else:
        count_by_n += 50
        print(str("start_index={}".format(str(count_by_n + 1))))
```

Comment: No, this is wrong. The syntax error is thrown because the variable which is declared as global is already used before this declaration. This is btw also written in the error message: "_name 'count_by_n' is assigned to before global declaration_". Besides that there is no need to declare anything to be global in this context. Test your own code without this line.

Comment: I did test this code and it works without warnings because here global is used before assigning a value: fixing the exact problem the warning was about. Check your words before posting a comment.

Comment: If I should check my words - why did you edit your answer accordingly? However - checking words before replying is a good advice: Note that I didn't doubt that you checked your code. I asked you to check your code _after deleting the line_ `global count_by_n`. Because global is not needed here. Of course using it doesn't result in a warning, but that's not a good reason to use any statement, right?